# In Elder Sign, If I free a locked die by defeating a monster, can I use it in the same turn?

Tags: elder-sign

If a monster locks a yellow die, can I use an item/spell to gain that die once I defeat the monster?

Also, I have not looked through the cards, but if there is a monster that locks the green die, would I gain the green die to use for rolling on the very turn I defeat that monster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not normally - monsters defeated within adventures are not destroyed and removed until the end of the adventure**.  Theoretically, this would work if you could destroy a monster instantly with some sort of monster-destroying special effect in the middle of the adventure; however, I believe that all such effects have timing windows that intentionally exclude the ability to do it at that time.